# Exception (ProviderIncompatibleException) on transactioned WCF service icm Entity Framework / SQL Server

Tags: c#, sql-server, wcf, entity-framework

I created a console application that reads my messages from a msmq. When a message comes in the application picks up the message.

When I make my WCF call transactioned with:

```
 [OperationBehavior(TransactionScopeRequired = true, TransactionAutoComplete = true)]
```

I get the following error when I query my database via my repository:

```
   at System.Data.Common.DbProviderServices.GetProviderManifestToken(DbConnection connection)
   at System.Data.Entity.ModelConfiguration.Utilities.DbConnectionExtensions.GetProviderInfo(DbConnection connection, DbProviderManifest& providerManifest)
   at System.Data.Entity.DbModelBuilder.Build(DbConnection providerConnection)
   at System.Data.Entity.Internal.LazyInternalContext.CreateModel(LazyInternalContext internalContext)
   at System.Data.Entity.Internal.RetryLazy`2.GetValue(TInput input)
   at System.Data.Entity.Internal.LazyInternalContext.InitializeContext()
   at System.Data.Entity.Internal.InternalContext.Initialize()
   at System.Data.Entity.Internal.InternalContext.GetEntitySetAndBaseTypeForType(Type entityType)
   at System.Data.Entity.Internal.Linq.InternalSet`1.Initialize()
   at System.Data.Entity.Internal.Linq.InternalSet`1.get_InternalContext()
   at System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.DbQuery`1.System.Linq.IQueryable.get_Provider()
   at System.Linq.Queryable.FirstOrDefault[TSource](IQueryable`1 source, Expression`1 predicate)
   at Repositories.Repository.BaseRepository`1.FindOneById(Int32 id) in 
   at Services.Service.ExporterService.ProcessImage(Int32 shotId, Int32 orderShotId) 
   at Services.ImageExporter.ExportImageService.ExportImage(Int32 shotId, Int32 exportShotId) in 
   at SyncInvokeExportImage(Object , Object[] , Object[] )
   at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.SyncMethodInvoker.Invoke(Object instance, Object[] inputs, Object[]& outputs)
   at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.DispatchOperationRuntime.InvokeBegin(MessageRpc& rpc)

   at System.Transactions.TransactionState.EnlistPromotableSinglePhase(InternalTransaction tx, IPromotableSinglePhaseNotification promotableSinglePhaseNotification, Transaction atomicTransaction)
   at System.Transactions.Transaction.EnlistPromotableSinglePhase(IPromotableSinglePhaseNotification promotableSinglePhaseNotification)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnection.EnlistNonNull(Transaction tx)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnection.Enlist(Transaction tx)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnectionTds.Activate(Transaction transaction)
   at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionInternal.ActivateConnection(Transaction transaction)
   at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.TryGetConnection(DbConnection owningObject, UInt32 waitForMultipleObjectsTimeout, Boolean allowCreate, Boolean onlyOneCheckConnection, DbConnectionOptions userOptions, DbConnectionInternal& connection)
   at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.TryGetConnection(DbConnection owningObject, TaskCompletionSource`1 retry, DbConnectionOptions userOptions, DbConnectionInternal& connection)
   at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionFactory.TryGetConnection(DbConnection owningConnection, TaskCompletionSource`1 retry, DbConnectionOptions userOptions, DbConnectionInternal& connection)
   at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionClosed.TryOpenConnection(DbConnection outerConnection, DbConnectionFactory connectionFactory, TaskCompletionSource`1 retry, DbConnectionOptions userOptions)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.TryOpen(TaskCompletionSource`1 retry)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.Open()
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlProviderServices.UsingConnection(SqlConnection sqlConnection, Action`1 act)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlProviderServices.UsingMasterConnection(SqlConnection sqlConnection, Action`1 act)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlProviderServices.GetDbProviderManifestToken(DbConnection connection)
   at System.Data.Common.DbProviderServices.GetProviderManifestToken(DbConnection connection)
```

When there is an exception (before the database call) in my code, the message is moved to the poison queue

If I remove this line it runs as I expect (it can call the database). The only problem is, when I get an exception in my code it does move the message to the poison queue.

How can I fix this?

Comment: What's the actual **error message** (not just the stack trace)....

Comment: The provider did not return a ProviderManifestToken string